# filenet process engine case insensitive query search

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-process-engine

I am using VWQueueQuery class of filenet api to search a value in file property. Now the problem is that search results are case sensitive but I want case insensitive search to happen. How can I do that

Thanks in advance
P.S. Query which I am sending is some what like this:
 `qFilter=Status LIKE '%Open%' and WorkFlowType = 'File' and FileSubject LIKE '%test%'
vwQueueQuery = vwQueue.createQuery (sortParam, null, null, qFlag,qFilter, null, qType);`

Comment: What FileNet product/version are you using?  What is the database (e.g. SQL Server, DB2, Oracle)

Comment: I am using IBM Filenet P8 platform version-4.5.1 and database being used is DB2 @JStark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer will differ based on your database.  For DB2, try to see if FileNet SQL will accept the upper keyword like this:
"select FIRSTNME from db2inst1.employee where **upper**(FIRSTNME) like 'EVA' "

REF: http://www.dbatodba.com/db2/how-to-do/how-to-do-search-ignoring-sensitive-case-on-db2